# MYSQL database query: suggest users to follow

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to implement suggestion function like Twitter's "Who to Follow" in a system that allows users to follow each other. I keep track of these subscriptions with a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `follower_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `following_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
)
```

I'm trying to get a list of Users that the current User is not already following.

So far I've tried using queries such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, s.follwer_id, s.enabled
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON u.id = s.follwer_id AND s.enabled = 0
WHERE u.id != 2
```

This query ends up giving me lots of NULLs and irrelevant rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, the `users` table refers to the users being followed.  You want the `follower_id` to be set to the current user and the `following_id` to be match back to users (for the `left join`):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, s.follower_id, s.enabled
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     subscriptions s
     ON u.id = s.following_id AND s.enabled = 0 and s.follower_id = 2
where s.following_id is null
```

Do note that the last two columns will always be `NULL`, because you are looking for users where there is no matching `subscriptions` record.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to me the reasoning behind the NULL columns, I've learned from this.